# How to get value while joining multiple tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an issue in my SQL query. I need to fetch value from DB by joining multiple tables but I could not get the data for some condition. My query is below:

```
    SELECT  b.member_id as b_member_id,b.rest_name,b.city,b.proviance,b.postal,
                b.address,b.country,b.person,b.mobile,b.url,b.status,b.premium,b.image,
                b.business_phone_no,b.email,b.multiple_image,b.latitude,b.longitude,
                b.quadrant,d.member_id as d_member_id,d.day_id,d.cat_id,d.subcat_id,
                d.comment,d.city,d.special_images,c.cat_id,c.special,sub.subcat_id,sub.subcat_name,
                sub.status,sl.day_id,sl.member_id,sl.date_from,sl.date_to 

    FROM db_restaurant_basic as b 
    LEFT JOIN db_restaurant_detail as d ON b.member_id=d.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_category as c ON d.cat_id=c.cat_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_subcategory as sub ON d.subcat_id=sub.subcat_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_special_images as sl ON d.day_id=sl.day_id 
    WHERE b.city='2' 
    AND d.day_id='1' 
    AND c.special='1' 
    AND sl.date_from <='2016-10-31' 
    AND sl.date_to >= '2016-10-31' 
    AND b.status=1 
    AND sub.status=1 
    AND sl.date_from !='' 
    AND sl.date_to !='' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      b.member_id,b.rest_name,b.city,b.proviance,b.postal,b.address,
                b.country,b.person,b.mobile,b.url,b.status,b.premium,b.image,
                b.business_phone_no,b.email,b.multiple_image,b.latitude,b.longitude,
                b.quadrant,d.member_id,d.day_id,d.cat_id,d.subcat_id,d.comment,
                d.city,d.special_images,c.cat_id,c.special,sub.subcat_id,sub.subcat_name,
                sub.status,sl.day_id,sl.member_id,sl.date_from,sl.date_to 
    FROM db_restaurant_basic as b 
    LEFT JOIN db_restaurant_detail as d ON b.member_id=d.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_category as c ON d.cat_id=c.cat_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_subcategory as sub ON d.subcat_id=sub.subcat_id 
    LEFT JOIN db_special_images as sl ON d.day_id=sl.day_id 
    WHERE b.city='2' 
    AND d.day_id='1' 
    AND c.special='1' 
    AND b.status=1 
    AND sub.status=1 
    AND sl.date_from ='' 
    AND sl.date_to ='' 
    ORDER BY b_member_id DESC;
```

I am not getting any value while `db_special_images` has no entry for this `sl.date_from ='' and sl.date_to =''`. I need the value should come while any one of following condition will match.

**Condition**

1. If  In `db_special_images` table (date_from ='' and date_to ='') and (date_from !='' and date_to !='').
2. If In `db_special_images` table (date_from ='' and date_to ='').
3. If In `db_special_images` table (date_from !='' and date_to !='').

I need if one of any above condition will match the value should come.

Comment: can you pls provide database structure.

Comment: Please format your query.

Comment: @kapil.dev : All the columns i have mentioned over here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : It has already formatted.

Comment: @satya  : it is very difficult to understand structure from ur query as it is not properly formatted

Comment: Break it up across multiple lines.  Someone else should not have to do this for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Please check my post again. I broke up it into multiple lines.

Comment: did the formatting how i always do it :)

Comment: The first condition seems contradictory to me -- `date_from` can't both be equal and unequal to an empty string.

Comment: Are the values in sl.date_from and sl.date_to actually null values, or are they empty strings?

Are you expecting records from db_special_images to be returned by the left join?

Comment: @AcatnamedMidnight : I have already given the conditions thats why i need to improve query. Can you help me ?

Comment: That is one of the ugliest queries I've ever seen. Are you trying to list specials or restaurants that have specials? You don't need `UNION`, just group your date conditions in parentheses. What happens if a special only has an end date, or only a start date? Better off doing `... AND (date_from = '' OR date_from <= '2016-10-31') AND ...` Denormalised data is harder to work with; select your one-to-one relationship data first, in its own query then the one-to-many data using the ids from from the first.

Comment: And if you're selecting practically every field from a table, don't bother listing each field; use `*` instead. E.g. `SELECT b.*, f.* FROM foo f LEFT JOIN bar b ON b.some_id = f.some_id`. Assuming you're using associative arrays or objects as results, reversing the order of the tables before the `FROM` is important to overwrite `NULL`s when no matches exist in the related table.